# set container height to a div height + add 100 pixels

Tags: jquery

I have this function

```
$(".container").width('1052').height($(".right").height());
```

And in the function the .container height is set by the .right height. Well, I also always want to add a 100 pixels to that number. How would I achieve that?

Is this possible without creating a separate variable?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe add a literal 100?

```
$(".container").width('1052').height($(".right").height()+100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".container").width('1052').height($(".right").height() + 100);
```